# VS Code always fail when try to install dependencies

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I tried using the example from here https://github.com/dejavuzhou/felix

And I have succeeded create my project from there. My project running well. It's just that when I open a project with VSCode, I always find notifications to download dependencies

[image]

But when I press `Install All` download always fail to all dependencies.

Error report from VSCode

```
Installing 8 tools at C:\Users\berth\go\bin
  gocode
  go-outline
  go-symbols
  guru
  gorename
  gocode-gomod
  goreturns
  golint

C:\Users\berth\go\src\github.com\berthojoris\ginbro\handlers>Finished running tool: C:\Go\bin\go.exe build -i -o C:\Users\berth\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-go8ZWFLb\go-code-check github.com\berthojoris\ginbro\handlers

C:\Users\berth\go\src\github.com\berthojoris\ginbro\handlers>Finished running tool: C:\Go\bin\go.exe vet ./...

Installing github.com/mdempsky/gocode FAILED
Installing github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline FAILED
Installing github.com/acroca/go-symbols FAILED
Installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru FAILED
Installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename FAILED
Installing github.com/stamblerre/gocode FAILED
Installing github.com/sqs/goreturns FAILED
Installing golang.org/x/lint/golint FAILED

8 tools failed to install.

gocode:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v github.com/mdempsky/gocode
github.com/mdempsky/gocode (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\github.com\mdempsky\gocode; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package github.com/mdempsky/gocode: exit status 1
github.com/mdempsky/gocode (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\github.com\mdempsky\gocode; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package github.com/mdempsky/gocode: exit status 1

go-outline:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline
github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil: exit status 1
github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil: exit status 1

go-symbols:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v github.com/acroca/go-symbols
github.com/acroca/go-symbols (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil: exit status 1
github.com/acroca/go-symbols (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil: exit status 1

guru:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru: exit status 1
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru: exit status 1

gorename:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename: exit status 1
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename: exit status 1

gocode-gomod:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v -d github.com/stamblerre/gocode
github.com/stamblerre/gocode (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/packages?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/packages?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/packages": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/packages?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/packages": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package golang.org/x/tools/go/packages: exit status 1
github.com/stamblerre/gocode (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/packages?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/packages?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/packages": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/packages?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/packages": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package golang.org/x/tools/go/packages: exit status 1

goreturns:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v github.com/sqs/goreturns
github.com/sqs/goreturns (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/imports": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/imports": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package golang.org/x/tools/imports: exit status 1
github.com/sqs/goreturns (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/imports": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/imports": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package golang.org/x/tools/imports: exit status 1

golint:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v golang.org/x/lint/golint
Fetching https://golang.org/x/lint/golint?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/lint/golint?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/lint/golint": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/lint", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/lint"} at https://golang.org/x/lint/golint?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/lint/golint": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/lint?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/lint?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/lint (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/lint?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/lint?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/lint": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/lint", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/lint"} at https://golang.org/x/lint?go-get=1
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil: exit status 1
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
package golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata: cannot find package "golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata" in any of:
    c:\go\src\golang.org\x\tools\go\gcexportdata (from $GOROOT)
    C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools\go\gcexportdata (from $GOPATH)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/lint/golint?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/lint/golint?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/lint/golint": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/lint", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/lint"} at https://golang.org/x/lint/golint?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/lint/golint": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/lint?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/lint?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/lint (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/lint?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/lint?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/lint": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/lint", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/lint"} at https://golang.org/x/lint?go-get=1
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil: exit status 1
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
package golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata: cannot find package "golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata" in any of:
    c:\go\src\golang.org\x\tools\go\gcexportdata (from $GOROOT)
    C:\Users\berth\go\src\golang.org\x\tools\go\gcexportdata (from $GOPATH)
```

How do I fix this problem because I am new to trying Golang.

Or should I ignore the warning from VSCode?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`dejavuzhou/felix`](https://github.com/dejavuzhou/felix) has a go.momd and go.sum: it depends on [go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules)

So make sure your VScode uses Go 1.11+ and

- no `GOPATH`
- `GO111MODULE` set

(see [troubleshooting](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#what-are-some-general-things-i-can-spot-check-if-i-am-seeing-a-problem))

As commented:

> - set `GO111MODULE` to the value on in your Windows System environment variable.
> - Then launch VSCode, and set in your JSon Users settings `go.toolsGopath` to a new empty folder, dedicated for tools.
> - Then try and build your project in VSCode, to see if your initial error message still persists.

Comment: In my env variables I already set. Do you mean I must remove this? @VonC

Comment: On my computer. `System Environment Variables`

Comment: @BerthoJoris OK. You have something in your System Environment Variables. Got it. But what did you set there? A GOPATH? GO111MODULE? Some other variable?

Comment: Hi @Vonc sorry for late response. I only add `GOPATH`, not `GO111MODULE`

Comment: I already delete `GOPATH` in my `System Environment Variables` but still failed when I press `Install All` in my VSCode notification

Comment: @BerthoJoris Did you relaunch VSCode after deleting GOPATH? The VSCode process inherited from the system environment variables, and modifying them would only work for *new* processes.

Comment: @BerthoJoris What version of Go are you using in VSCode? And is GO111MODULE set?

Comment: Yes... I already delete and restart my computer after this. But always the same

Comment: @BerthoJoris Do you have `"go.toolsGopath"` set in your VSCode USer settings?

Comment: go.toolsGopath Not find in my VSCode setting (setting.json)

Comment: @BerthoJoris Try and set it to a new empty folder: that will be a GOPATH dedicated to your tools (as opposed to your projects which will not use any GOPATH at all). Make sure `GO111MODULE` is set to the value `on`.

Comment: How to check `GO111MODULE` setting ON or OFF in my current project? Is that in my computer setting? I mean `System Environment Variables` or in every project folder?

Comment: Before launching VSCode, open a CMD terminal and type `set GO`: if you see `GO111MODULE=on`, you are good to go.

Comment: I found `Environment variable GO not defined` when I type `set GO`

Comment: @BerthoJoris OK. Try and set it, then launch VSCode, check `go.toolsGopath` is set and try install all your tools. Only then try and build your project.

Comment: How do I do? Try to set what?

Comment: @BerthoJoris I meant: set `GO111MODULE` to the value `on` in your Windows System environment variable. Then launch VSCode, and set in your JSonn Users settings `go.toolsGopath` to a new empty folder, dedicated for tools. Then try and build your project in VSCode, to see if your initial error message still persists.

Comment: Ok, I will try it

Comment: Everything went perfectly.. Thanks @VonC